# ElasticSearh searching by part of word if hyphen presents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have, for example, following strings: `11-22-33`, `22-33-44`, `33-44-55`, `44-55-66` and I'd like to find only `11-22-33`. But ES returns me all except last.

Also, later I will need to search by parts `*11-22*` and it should return me first record.

Comment: Please, add the queries, you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your fileds are analyzed your strings will be stored as `["11","22","33"]`, `["22","33","44"]`, `["33","44","55"]`, `["44","55","66"]`. When you search `11-22-33` it also will be tokenized as `["11","22","33"]` and all but the last one have a relevance with that so they will return. If you want store your strings as they are you need to set your fields as `not_analyzed`

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same problem. Even after doing `not_analyzed` it was not working. The reason was that the field I added was a new field and I was trying without having modified the mapping. By default, while inserting a not-mapped field, Elasticsearch uses the default mapping.